# jlist elements are not displaying dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jlist

i am writing client -server chat app. i have created jlist in client GUI, so that online clients can be dispalyed. But when different objetcs of that client GUI are created, jlist does not display all clients,i.e if one client is created in one object, it will not be displayed by other object.
Here is my code:

```
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    static List<String> Client = new ArrayList<String>();
    public GUI() {
        initComponents();

    }
    public GUI(String hostname,int port, String user_name) throws  Exception{
        initComponents();
        my_name = user_name;
        s = new Socket("localhost", 80);
        Client.add(user_name);
        for(int i=0;i<Client.size();i++){
            model.addElement(Client.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you certain that you use that model as the model of your `JList`. That is not shown in the code. Other guess would be threading issues, as indicated in the answer of @mKorbel

Comment: @Robin, yes it is .jList1.setModel(model); it is given in initilization

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

- you have an issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html),
- Swing isn't thread safe
- all updates to the [Swing GUi must be done on EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html),

  a) output from `Socket` never notified `EDT`,

  b) add a new `Item` to the `DefaultListModel`  never notified `EDT`,

  c) simple workaround is wrap code line `model.addElement(Client.get(i))`; to the `invokeLater()`
- this question could be [booking example about why using SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

EDIT `invokeLater of jlist?`, not please see

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        model.addElement(Client.get(i));
    }
});
```

Comment: do you starting your GUI from [Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), create GUI, show GUI, start Socket (best of options will be from SwingWorker, publish() reply to the ListModel, otherwise GUI will be freeze untill Socked ended), update ListModel with data from Socker